# ImportError PyQt5 Anaconda

Tags: python, qt, anaconda, pyqt5

I am trying to use PyQt5 installed via pip in an Anaconda enviroment on Windows 10 x64.
This is how i create my environemnt:

```
conda create --name qt python=3.6
activate qt
pip install pyqt5
```

When running an example application i get an error:

> File "pyqt_test.py", line 16, in 
>       from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
>   ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Installing Python by downloading it from python.org and then installing pyqt5 works as expected.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why are you using pip to install a package to a conda environment? Why not use `conda install pyqt5`?

Answer (score 4):

Just run into the same problem, Miloslav is right about the problem, actually it seems that conda should maybe provide a python3.dll as well, see here for the discussion https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1394.

In short just use conda to install pyqt5 by running:

```
conda install pyqt
```

this install the latest pyqt bindings which is currently pyqt 5.6

Comment: Then in order to use this does one type `import pyqt` and then it imports pyqt5?

Comment: You haven't told us about proper way to install pyqt bindings, just installing pyqt results in failing imports.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of missing `Python3.dll` (stub dll, that re-exports `Python3x.dll` functions, so that one version of extension can work for multiple versions of python).

If your Python distro doesn't bundle python3.dll, you can try one from WinPython (https://winpython.github.io/).

At least the 2017/04/01 versions should have it.

1) Download WinPython ('Zero' version suffices; must be same "main version" - 3.5/3.6  -and "bitness" - 32/64 - as your Python !!!).

2) Extract to some temp directory, take the python3.dll and stick it into your python dir, next to the python3x.dll.

3) Enjoy working QT

Comment: I have followed this steps, but did not have any success. Any ideas? Although the autocompletion in PyCharm works and the import line is not underlined as if the package could not be found.

Comment: @Iskrinjar It was a long time ago, at the time this was the major source (versions of python have advanced ...). It might be you need newer Python3.dll (if you had one and overwrote it, try to get it back). The only definitive way is to use some dependency walker to figure what is wrong with your install. For example this one: http://www.dependencywalker.com/  -- open the .pyd module you are trying to load and check missing imports (try to find the file in your python tree, or figure out what is the correct version to download, then stick it in some dir  where python looks for dlls)...

Answer (score 1):

In my case,Firstly i installed pyqt:

```
conda install pyqt
```

Then i deleted the qt.conf file located next to python.exe. Next pyqt5 installation succeeded:

```
conda install pyqt5
```

ref: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/138